# how can i display vuejs mixin data in the ui in laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

mixin/error.js

```
export default {

    data(){
        return{
            text:"This is a text from the mixin",
        }
    },
};
```

**i imported the mixin globally in my app.js as**

import error from './mixins/error'

Vue.mixin(error);

**In my login.vue component, if i try to display the mixin data in a method, it works fine... like this**

```
showMixinData(){
    alert(this.text);
}
```

**but when i try to display it in the template tag like this**

```
<template>
   <div>
      <h1> {{ this.text }} </h1>
   </div>
</template>
```

**it doesn't work**

Answer (score 0):

This works as expected:

```js
Vue.mixin({
    data() {
        return{
            text:"This is a text from the mixin"
        }
    }
})
Vue.component('alert', {template:'<div><b>{{text}}</b></div>'})
new Vue().$mount('div')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div><alert></alert><div>{{text}}</div></div>
```

Comment: the text variable gets displayed at run-time in the debugger but in the vue conponent, if you do this.text or text, it gives an error......but it a method if you display this.text, it works